# How do I make a container take up the full row height and scale responsively with img-responsive images in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a responsive grid of panels and all of the panels that are images scale appropriately using bootstraps img-responsive class but one of the panels is not an image and I can't get that container to scale appropriately to the height of the other column in it's row.

Here's a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/n8CB4ZTpD1#) with the sample code. The top left container needs to be the same height as the container to it's right, and it should scale proportionally with the image as the window shrinks.

EDIT - i fixed the link above the images are now visible

Answer (score 1):

Im not seeing the images on the link you have sent so this makes it difficult to understand properly, however have you tried something like this;

```
.class {
max-height: 100px; /* Set this to the same px height as your images */
height: auto !important;
Width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I have fixed the images in the link above though.

Comment: Have you tried putting a height on the column? like so;

.col-md-8 {
   height: 195px;
  }
.bgc-grey {
   background-color: #ccc;
  max-height: 195px;
  height: 100%;
}

Comment: If I set a height it's fine, but it needs to scale as the images scale down so I can't do a set height. I have it working right now with JS but that's not ideal.

Comment: What you could do in that case is set a media query for css so that as the page gets smaller you can change the height of the column?

Comment: The page scales every pixel you shrink the window, I would need a lot of media queries. Otherwise that is probably what I would be doing.